# Is this content of a website a gif or a video?

Tags: html, gif, multimedia

If you go to [this website](https://elpais.com/), and scroll down to kind of the third "set" of pages, you see a news, under the title of "Destacados", signaled below in red:

[image]

Now, the image of that news is dynamic, like a gif. I went to the source code of the page, and the image seems to be contained here:

```
<div class="articulo__interior">
<figure class="foto  foto_video " itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    // Hash con los datos para el reproductor de video
    var datosVideo_389 = {};


    var anchoReproductor_389 = 0;
    var altoReproductor_389  = 0;


    var urlFotogramaFijo_389    = url_cache + '';
    var urlPrimerFotograma_389  = url_cache + '';

    datosVideo_389.tipo          = 'iframe';
    datosVideo_389.id_multimedia = '';

    datosVideo_389.anchoPlayer   = anchoReproductor_389;
    datosVideo_389.altoPlayer    = altoReproductor_389;
    datosVideo_389.caratula      = urlFotogramaFijo_389;
    datosVideo_389.publiActiva   = true;
    datosVideo_389.keywordsVideo = 'elpais,portada';
    datosVideo_389.urls = Array();
                      datosVideo_389.codigo = '<iframe src=\"//elpais.com/estaticos/2018/07/entrevista/video/video-felipe.html\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\"><\/iframe>';

    datosVideo_389.urlNoticia  = '/elpais/2018/07/10/actualidad/1531220458_959403.html';
    datosVideo_389.tituloVideo           = 'Los papeles secretos de Felipe González';
    datosVideo_389.tagsIds               = '31578,11610,32436,72041,84210,33281,20979,46697,69816,84640,28504,75423,81138,28501,36715,75421,30342,65941';
    datosVideo_389.tagsNombreNormalizado = 'felipe_gonzalez_marquez_a,alfonso_guerra_a,fidel_castro_a,santos_julia_a,elecciones_generales_1989_a,francisco_fernandez_ordonez_a,carlos_solchaga_a,jose_maria_maravall_a,rocio_martinez_sampere_a,gal_grupos_antiterroristas_liberacion_a,elecciones_generales_a,terrorismo_estado_a,eta_a,elecciones_a,grupos_terroristas_a,terrorismo_a,espana_a,politica_a';

    datosVideo_389.tituloPlayer  = '';
    datosVideo_389.duracionVideo = '';
    datosVideo_389.portal_creacion  = '';
    datosVideo_389.seccion_creacion = '';
    datosVideo_389.un_creacion      = '';

    // Llamada para pintar el reproductor de video
    reproductorMultimedia(datosVideo_389);


//]]>
</script>
<meta itemprop="url" content="https://ep01.epimg.net/iconos/v1.x/v1.0/promos/promo_og_elpais.png">
<meta itemprop="width" content="200">
<meta itemprop="height" content="200">
</figure>
```

But I cannot figure out what exactly it is. Is it a video? Or a gif? If the former, why not use the latter, perhaps easier and less demanding in terms of resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'image' is a video. One way to confirm this is to use inspector and view the source of the page, then locate the element.

[image]